# Java PDF Generation iText Alternative

Tags: pdf-generation

I am brand new to pdf generation or rendering. I am working on a application to replace iText and create kind of a RESTful endpoints using any Java related PDF APIs.
The library should be able to convert images and.., others to PDF.

- Read/fill the data from PDF programmatically and also merge.
- Also, if we can host it ourselves that would be the best choice.
  Could you please provide some insight into this?

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are off-topic on stack overflow. You may want to try on [softwarerecs.se] instead. And as you want to replace iText, please don't forget to mention in which aspect that alternative should differ from iText, otherwise the obvious recommendation would be iText itself.

Comment: You may check [Spire.Pdf for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-java.html) which is capable of generating PDF, converting images to PDF, reading text/images/tables in PDF and merging PDFs. You can explore more about it by visiting its [documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/JAVA/Spire.PDF-for-JAVA/Program-Guide/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide-Content-for-JAVA.html).

Comment: @James, Thank you for the details. Will try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: you do have a [containerized version of iText](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-xjadp4eijqge4).

Comment: @James, Spre.PDF may not be the option due to the constraint we have. Also we are actually planning to move away completely from iText. Any other suggestions you may think of  ? Could you please suggest when you get chance. Thank you again..

Comment: @AndréLemos, we are completely moving away from iText. Do you think of any other product that would be good to explore ?

Comment: I'm a VP of Product at iText @RKYetch, so that would be a no.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a "Java related PDF API" but since you want to go REST anyway:

We use a headless Chrome in a docker container for generating PDFs. A good starting point is [hc-pdf-server](https://github.com/uyamazak/hc-pdf-server). We use it as an internal service using REST.

Note that this way, documents need to be designed using HTML and CSS. Also, you need to use a template engine in order to insert contents into your documents. We use [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/). It is simple and does the job.

Comment: got it. Thanks, alot. I went ahead and implemented using OpenPDF API.